# How can I add an agree to terms and conditions checkbox before users can add items to cart on specific pages?

Tags: html, checkbox, checkout

This question may seem long, but on my website, I have add to cart buttons so people can purchase my products. I have 2 sections of products, digital downloads, and physical products. Both products digital and physical have the same add-to-cart buttons.

What I want to do is add the agree to terms checkbox below the add to cart button ONLY for digital products. Is there a way to add this checkbox on a specific page basis that connects with that specific page add to cart button?

I would be happy to show you my website if that helps! Thank you, guys!

As requested my website is https://www.skylerjacksonfineart.com

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yes, showing us your website would be helpful. Have a good time here while you're at it.

Comment: Thank you! My website is https://www.skylerjacksonfineart.com.

Comment: Also, here is link to something similiar to what I am trying to accomplish: https://www.termsfeed.com/i-agree-checkbox/

Comment: What technology would you like to use? JavaScript?

Comment: Is HTML JavaScript? I believe I can add HTML to each specific page.

Comment: You can add JavaScript to HTML. Nearly all browsers nowadays support JS.

Comment: That would work then.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do so with javascript.
You just add a javascript block at the end of your html to have it check for the checkbox being checked.  If not checked, disable the button.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp gives you the functions to check the checkbox, then just use the same getElementByID using your button ID to control the button.

Probably something like:
**document.getElementById("yourBtn").enabled = document.getElementById("yourCheckbox").checked;**
may work...

Comment: I will check this out, but how do I find the "yourBtn" and "yourcheckbox"?